# Why is visual studio saying this is "type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected"?

Tags: c#

I've looked through this over and over again, I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. After looking it up some common issue where just people added extra braces or just forgetting one but I've looked through it and cant seem to find where I messed up. What is causing this error and why is it happening? It's showing the errors on lines 120 and 105.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Rocket.Core.Plugins;
using Rocket.Core.Logging;
using Rocket.Unturned.Events;
using Rocket.Unturned.Player;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Rocket.Unturned;
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace VipTeleport
{
    public class VipTeleport : RocketPlugin
    {
        public static VipTeleport Instance;
        public Vector3 DeathPos;
        public UnturnedPlayer movePlayer;
        public bool canTeleport = false;
        public int timerT = 0;
        public List<string> players = new List<string>();
        public List<PlayerFinder> playerVars = new List<PlayerFinder>();
        public PlayerFinder playerInfo;
        public string steamId;
        public int[] playerTimer = new int[24];
        public int[] playerSteamID = new int[24];
        public bool[] playersCanTeleport = new bool[24];
        public int index;


        protected override void Load()
        {
            VipTeleport.Instance = this;
            //Just console logs for the plugin in RocketApi on unturneds server console
            Logger.LogWarning("##################################");
            Logger.LogWarning("#Vip Teleport Loaded Sucessfully!#");
            Logger.LogWarning("##################################");
            Logger.LogWarning("#         Version  V.1.0         #");
            Logger.LogWarning("##################################");
        }

        protected override void Unload()
        {

        }



        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            U.Events.OnPlayerConnected += (UnturnedPlayer player) =>
            {
                int addTo = Convert.ToInt32(player.CSteamID);
                foreach (int f in playerSteamID)
                {
                    if (f == 0)
                    {
                        playerSteamID[f] = addTo;
                        foreach (int i in playerTimer)
                        {
                            playerTimer[f] = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        foreach (bool t in playersCanTeleport)
                        {
                            playersCanTeleport[f] = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
            //Listener for player Death
            UnturnedPlayerEvents.OnPlayerDead += (UnturnedPlayer player, Vector3 Vector3) =>
            {
                int localSteamID = Convert.ToInt32(player.CSteamID);
                foreach (int i in playerSteamID)
                {
                    if (i == localSteamID)
                    {
                        index = i;
                        playerTimer[index] = 120;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(playerTimeVars);
                aTimer.Interval = playerTimer[index];
                aTimer.Enabled = true;

                if ((playerTimer[index] <= 120) && (playerInfo.timerT > 0))
                {
                    playerInfo.canTeleport = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    playerInfo.canTeleport = false;
                    playerInfo.timerT = 0;
                }
            };


            U.Events.OnPlayerDisconnected += (UnturnedPlayer player) =>
            {

            };


            public int indexHolder(int i)
            {
                return i;
            }

            public void playerTimeVars(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                int localIndex = indexHolder(index);
                playerTimer[localIndex] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is always good idea to provide [MCVE] - it usually either solve the issue or at least demonstrate good effort. In current state your post will likely be closed as "typographical error" (and such "wall of code" posts show low respect for others time - but this rarely stops anyone from asking/answering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last two methods need to be below a curly brace, currently they are inside the `FixedUpdate()` method.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
...

    U.Events.OnPlayerDisconnected += (UnturnedPlayer player) =>
    {
    };
}

public int indexHolder(int i)
{
    return i;
}

public void playerTimeVars(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{     
    int localIndex = indexHolder(index);
    playerTimer[localIndex] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FixedUpdate()` method hasn't got enough brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The methods `public int indexHolder(int i), public void playerTimeVars(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)` are placed inside `private void FixedUpdate()` method which is the source of this error. Place them outside `FixedUpdate` and it should fix the error